# IE counter-progress (CSS)

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I'm reading up on opacity CSS and just grew further contempt for IE. Can anyone shed some light on this counter-progress?

**CSS for 50% opacity...**

in all browsers except IE: `opacity: .5;`

in IE 5-7: `filter: alpha(opacity=50);`

in IE 8: `-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";`

[[source]](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html)

They suggest in order to have your CSS work with IE the two should be used together:

```
.opaque {
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);                  
}
```

I guess my question is, what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft didn't implement native in-browser CSS opacity support until IE9. They did provide a method for CSS to invoke DirectX in Windows and let that system handle such things. Hence filter and -ms-filter. Filter was the original version, but was a completely non-standard CSS property and would cause css to not validate. With IE8 they at least change the property name to use the pseudo-standard dash prefix notation to indicate it's non-standard.

Comment: So the confusing syntax is a form of disclaimer? I was aware of the extra activity that this `-ms-filter` tag invokes, I've just never understood why they couldn't have their DirectX call respond to the same CSS syntax as the other browsers respond to.